# Configuracion de Nginx para dos servicios web en la misma ip

Tags: linux, webservice, go

estoy haciendo una aplicacion en Go que contiene HttpHandlers para sitio1.com y HttpHandlers para sitio2.com . En la configuracion de nginx, agregue un archivo para cada sitio en la carpeta sites-available e hice un symlink de estos archivos en sites-enabled. Asi se ve la configuracion del sitio2 por ejemplo. El sitio1 es igual solo que esta en el puerto 8080 y cambia el server name.

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name site2.com;

location /processing {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
}
    
location / {
    return 404 '{"error": "Not Found"}';
}



server { 
listen 80;
    server_name site1.com;

    location /api/users { 
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }

location / {
    return 404 '{"error": "Not Found"}'; 
}
```

}

luego hice el include en nginx.conf de estos dos archivos. Ademas de esto modifique etc/hosts para que ambos tengan la ip 127.0.0.1

El problema que tengo es que sitio1.com responde a endpoints que son solo funcionalidad de sitio2.com y viceversa.. Basicamente da igual el nombre del dominio siempre y cuando ponga el puerto correcto y el endpoint correcto.

Tambien probe en hacer dos .go por separado uno para sitio1 y otro para sitio2, cada uno con sus endpoints y escuchando el puerto especifico para esos endpoints. Aun asi sigue sin funcionar. Alguna idea como puedo solucionar esto?

Comment: ¿Que querés decir con "siempre y cuándo ponga el el puerto correcto"?

Comment: Que si hago una solicitud a los endpoints de site2 que esta en el 8081 , por ej: curl --request POST \
  --url http://site1.com:8081/processing/submit  me responde bien. Y no es el comportamiento que quiero, ya que ese es un endpoints de site2

Comment: Comprendo, solo que esto no tiene nada que ver con [tag:ngix], pues en este solo abres el puerto 80. Sugiero que coloques las etiquetas que correspondan a la tecnología con la que sea que abres el puerto 8081. Un saludo.